# AttributeError: "type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'Worker'"

Tags: python, object, inheritance

Taking a class on Python coding and trying to use inheritance to code an answer to this problem: Write an Employee class that keeps data attributes for the following piece of information:

Employee name
Employee ID
Employee phone #

Next, write a class named ProductionWorker class should keep data attributes for the following information:

Shift number (an integer, such as 1, 2, 3)
Room (bakery, topping, Quality control)
Hourly pay rate

The workday is divided into two shifts: day and night. The shift attribute will hold an integer value representing the shift that the employee works. The day shift 1 and the night shift is shift 2. Write the appropriate accessors and mutator methods for each class.

Once you have written the classes, write a program that creates an object of the ProductionWorker class which prompts the user to enter data for each of the object's data attributes. Store the data in the object, then use the object's accessor methods to retrieve it and display it to the screen.

Why am I getting the error I described in the title?

My Code:

````
class Employee(object):#Creates Superclass Employee
    
    def __init__(self,name,EmplId,EmpPhone):#Creates Employee class with several parameters
        self.name = name#Initial Attribute for Employee Name
        self.EmplId = EmplId#Initial Attribute for Employee ID #
        self.EmpPhone = EmpPhone#Initial attribute for Employee Phone #
       
  
class Worker(Employee):#Creates Subclass of Employee called Worker
       
    def __init__(self,name,EmplId,ShiftNum,EmpPhone,PayRate):#Set initial state of Worker Subclass
        Employee.__init__(self,name,EmplId,EmpPhone) 
        self.ShiftNum = ShiftNum#Initial Shift number value for class Worker
        self.PayRate = PayRate#Initial Payrate for class Worker

    
def main():#Creates Main method
    WorkerName = " "
    WorkerIDNum = " "
    WorkerShiftNum = 0
    WorkerPayRate = 0.0
    WorkerPhoneNum = " "

    #Getting data attributes to passed into Employee and Worker classes
    WorkerName = input("Enter the Workers name: ")
    WorkerIDNum = ("Enter the Workers Id Number: ")
    WorkerShiftNum = input ("Enter the Workers shift number (1,2,or 3): ")
    WorkerPayRate = input ("Enter the works payrate in dollars an cents: ")
    WorkerPhoneNum = input ("Enter the employees 9 Digit phone number:")
    
    worker = Employee.Worker(WorkerName,WorkerIDNum,WorkerShiftNum,WorkerPhoneNum,WorkerPayRate)
    #Above line creates an Instance of the Employee superclass and Worker subclass called "worker"
    #Values the user entered are pass in as attributes to the object.

    #Printing User entered information
    print("Worker information entered: ")
    print("Name: ", worker.name)
    print("EMployee ID Number: ", worker.EmplId)
    print("Employee Shift Number: ", worker.ShiftNum)
    print("Worker Hourly Payrate: $", worker.PayRate)
main()```
````

Comment: change `Employee.Worker` to `Worker`. Also, everything you store from `input` will be a `str`. You will need to cast some of it to `int`, and possibly `float`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem was provided in the comments... you must instantiate only the subclass (ie. `Worker`, not `Employee.Worker`), but I see more problems. My example below illustrates one way to fix them. You are creating a lot of arbitrary values, and not performing any checks or limits on them. Everything comes from outside of your class and needs to be clumsily injected into the `__init__` arguments. Then to print the `Worker` you gather all of the data externally and format it into print statements. Why not make your classes smart enough to handle all of this internally?

To put this another way. You are basically just grabbing a bunch of junk, throwing it in a class constructor and calling it a `Worker`. You should be able to just call `Worker` and it handles getting, formatting and limiting everything that it expects.

Below we store all the final values in private variables. We tie all assignments to "setters" and trigger those "setters" in `__init__`. This allows us to force variables to satisfy certain conditions before we accept them. It also allows us to change properties of the Worker (after instantiation) while following the exact same system.

```
#Creates Superclass Employee
class Employee(object):
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.__name
        
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name:str) -> None:
        while not name:
            name  = input("Enter The Worker's Name: ")
            
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def phone(self) -> str:
        return self.__phone
        
    @phone.setter
    def phone(self, phone) -> None:
        phone = f'{phone}'
        #get and check phone
        while not phone.isdigit() or len(phone) != 10:
            phone = input("Enter The Worker's 10 digit Phone Number: ")
            
        #store phone    
        self.__phone = phone
       
    @property
    def eid(self) -> int:
        return self.__eid
        
    @eid.setter
    def eid(self, eid) -> None:
        if not isinstance(eid, int):
            eid = f'{eid}'
            #get and check employee id
            while not eid.isdigit():
                eid = input("Enter The Worker's ID Number: ")
            eid = int(eid)
            
        #store id
        self.__eid = eid
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.name, self.phone, self.eid = '', '', ''
        

#Creates Subclass of Employee called Worker  
class Worker(Employee):
    @property
    def shift(self) -> int:
        return self.__shift
        
    @shift.setter
    def shift(self, shift) -> None:
        if not isinstance(shift, int) or (isinstance(shift, int) and shift not in (1, 2, 3)):
            shift = f'{shift}'
            #get and check shift number
            while not shift.isdigit() or not shift in ('1', '2', '3'):
                shift = input("Enter The Worker's Shift Number (1, 2, 3): ")
            shift = int(shift)
                
        #store shift
        self.__shift = shift
        
    @property
    def rate(self) -> float:
        return self.__rate
        
    @rate.setter
    def rate(self, rate) -> None:
        if not isinstance(rate, (float, int)):
            rate = f'{rate}'
            #get and check pay rate
            while True:
                try:
                    float(rate)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                rate = input("Enter The Worker's Pay Rate in Dollars and Cents: ")
            rate = float(rate)
                
        #store rate
        self.__rate  = rate
    
    def __init__(self):
        Employee.__init__(self) 
        self.shift, self.rate = '', ''
        
    #for printing the worker props
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Worker Information:\n\tname: {self.name}\n\tid: {self.eid}\n\tphone: {self.phone}\n\tshift: {self.shift}\n\trate: {self.rate}'


#this is so much cleaner. Make a Worker and print the instance.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = Worker()
    print(worker)
```